# How to add HTML entities in Dart?

Tags: dart, html-entities, dart-html

I want to add [HTML entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080122/#entities) like `&nbsp;` or `&amp;` using a Dart class. I tried this :

```dart
my_element.nodes.add(new Text('&amp;&copy;'));
```

but as mentioned in [Text class doc](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Text.html), markup is parsed into information, meaning everything is escaped, I guess. I read [Node class doc](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Node.html) looking for an Entity class; there is none, and I don't want to embed my entity in a tag:

```dart
my_element.nodes.add(new Element.html('<span>&amp;&copy;</span>'));
```

Which class should I use to add an HTML entity ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DocumentFragment](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/DocumentFragment.html) will do the job. This:

```dart
my_element.nodes.add(new DocumentFragment.html('&amp;&copy;'));
```

will output `&©` in your HTML document.